# Есть ли способ объеденить 2 бинарника, написанных на разных языках в один?

Tags: c++, c

Есть бинарник `main.o` который был скомпилирован на g++ и `fun.o`, скомпилированный на gcc. При этом в своем коде main использует ф-цию из файла `fun.c`. Могу ли я объеденить эти два файла в одну прогу?

Comment: Ну это надо смотреть в документацию к gcc. Или просто попробовать слинковать, сразу станет понятно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема, описанная в комментариях — наличие [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C++) в объектных файлах, компилируемых C++. Поэтому если вы включаете header на C в файл на C++, он декларирует функцию по бинарным правилам для C++, и эту декларацию компоновщик не может сопоставить с кодом функции в объектом файле на C. Попробуйте записать так в общем заголовочном файле:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// тут код на C

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

---

С точки зрения стандарта, функция, описанная внутри `extern "C"`, имеет C linkage. Впрочем, если вы знаете, что это такое, вы и так знаете ответ на этот вопрос.

Comment: добавил этот код в файл с кодом с++, там, где используется ф-ция из бинарника скомпилированного на Си. Ничего не получилось, пишет: `expected unqualified-id before string constant
     extern "C" {`

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch: Нет-нет, это ж надо в header-файл на C. Из C++-файла уберите.

Comment: работает! Спасибо, большое)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!

Comment: Можешь еще ответить на такой вопрос: если в хэдэре функция на с++ надо ли делать анологичные записи?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch: Нет, не нужно. По умолчанию, если вы пишете на C++, компилятор создаёт имена функций в бинарном стандарте C++. Единственный случай — это если вы из C вызываете функцию на C++, тогда нужно её тоже декорировать. Например, как `extern "C++"` (если компилятор такое умеет).

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, если хотите, чтобы компилируемые С++ компилятором функции также были доступны и из Си, то обязательно добавляйте к ним `extern "C"` (естественно, такие крестовые особенности, как overloading будут утрачены).

Comment: @avp: По идее, можно наоборот, `extern "C++"`, если объектный файл сгенерирован компилятором в режиме C++. Gcc должен поддерживать вроде.

Comment: @VladD, где-то может gcc и понимает `extern "C++"`, но не в моей убунте (там эти слова понимает g++)

Answer (score 2):

Если версия g++ и gcc совпадает, то слинкуется без проблем.

Comment: вот у меня при линковке выскакивает ошибка:

Comment: main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xa9): undefined reference to `sortFun(int*, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'enigma' failed
make: *** [enigma] Error 1

Comment: хотя когда точно такой же код компилировать полностью на С - то без проблем